# Outlook Web Addin manifest creates 'Invalid xsi:type=Event'

Tags: xml, office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are creating an outlook web add-in which includes the `Onsend` feature.

The template was working fine without adding the `ExtensionType` tag in manifest but when we added that tag, it triggers an error ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOfTm.png)):

```
<ExtensionPoint xsi:type="Events">
  <Event Type="ItemSend" FunctionExecution="synchronous" FunctionName="validateBody" />
</ExtensionPoint>
```

We [searched further and found](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/issues/2) that adding a `verionoverrides` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPcxd.jpg)) tag corrects the error but during compilation, it throws an error:

> Failed to deploy the manifest file to the Exchange server. An internal server error occurred. The operation failed., Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Does anyone confront the same error or can anyone please guide towards a right path to resolve this?

Complete Manifest: https://files.fm/f/hca3npdt

Comment: Kindly as for the details if needed.

Comment: We also tested this issue on Visual Studio 2017, but still no luck!

Comment: Yes, adding the <VersionOverrides> tag should work. [See if this doc helps you](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins). Would you be able to upload your manifest file for us to take a look?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I have added manifest file in question. Please have a look and suggest if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every approach out there finally I found a way and it was too easy. Actually what you have to do is just copy all code from your manifest file (.xml) and replace it with the one which you have published on server or your individual manifest file whatever your scenario is.

This was the solution and I confirmed by putting a test dialog at onsend event and it worked. Hope this will be helpful for someone who is in the same boat.

PS. I think the documentation should mention this workaround so that it would be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The following snipped was included under version overrides 1.0:

[image]With no extension points this isn't a valid part of the manifest. Once this is removed you should be able to install the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your correction but we tried that way and we faced this error : [link] https://imgur.com/a/ZtxTP

Comment: I get the same issue on my side.

Comment: @JaydevSolanki Visual Studio is showing the validation error in your screenshot because it's using an older, local version of the manifest schema to validate the manifest. After removing the section of the manifest shown in the answer, as it looks like you did, the manifest should install successfully, despite the local validation error.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT  The error still persist and we have tried removing and adding code block you have suggested. Is there any other way around to resolve this validation error ? Something like updating the schema or anything else.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT I'm hitting the same error. Here's the XML that I'm trying to install: https://pastebin.com/ZFDxeWJQ Here's the error that is being spit out: https://imgur.com/a/SWWUO

Comment: The local schema validation error should be safe to ignore. It shouldn't prevent the add-in from functioning once installed.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Thanks for your quick responses, much appreciated! The errors aren't from the local schema validator, but the Office 365 Admin window. Here's another screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/WB8Mj

Comment: It looks like you're using Centralized Deployment to install the add-in. Until very recently, Centralized Deployment only supported Word/Excel/PowerPoint add-in deployment. You may see Outlook add-in support in Preview. As an alternative, to install an Outlook add-in for a single user, try the "Store" button in Outlook Desktop or "Manage add-ins" under settings in OWA. To install add-ins for an organization, look for "add-ins" in the Exchange Admin Center (to open EAC from Admin Center, look for Exchange under "Admin centers").

Comment: @JaydevSolanki for your manifest, it may install through Store/Manage add-ins but you will need to change the relative URLs in the manifest to full URLs.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Thank you! Was able to install through the Exchange Admin interface.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT In my case the manifest cannot be compiled even so installation issue is not in the area of concern.